# Is there suitable statistics test to compare number of observations from 2 groups (1x2, Fishers?)?

Tags: statistics

I did a research on group of cases and controls. During my research I observed **7  variants** in group of cases while I **did not observe** any in controls.

I would like to test is there a **significant difference between 7:0 finding**.

I thought of doing Fishers exact test, but not sure how it can be performed on 1x2 table and is it a suitable test for such analysis. Also, I thought of correction, to exclude 0 from statistics, so maybe to compare 7.5 and **0.5**.

Is there **a better test to perform** for such a cases?

All suggestions are welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `2x2` table, but you are ignoring one of the rows. You need to add how many non-variants you had in each group. The answer to your question depends on that. Say you had 7 variants out of 30 cases and 0 variants out of 20 controls. Your contingency table would look like this:

|  | Cases | Controls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Variants | 7 | 0 |
| Non-variants | 23 | 20 |

Without this information, testing makes no sense. Now, you can use an exact test, such as Fisher's (conditional) or Barnard's (unconditional). I have described an unconditional test that seems to be more powerful than those ([link](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.14315)). In this case,

```
> library(mtest)
> m.test(list(c(7, 23), c(0, 20)))
[1] 0.01702871
```